# What ID numbers to use for Notifications

Tags: android

```
public static final int NOTIFY_FAILED = 1;

private final Notification displayErrorNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, "Communication Error", System.currentTimeMillis());
private void displayNotificationError(String message) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    displayErrorNotification.number++;
    displayErrorNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Failed x ("+displayErrorNotification.number+")", message, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_FAILED, displayErrorNotification);
}
```

In this example I have used 1 for failed notifications but what if other programs also use the number 1 for their notifications.

What would happen when I do this:

```
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFY_FAILED);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any number you like.

The IDs and Notifications are per-application — you do not need to worry about other applications changing or cancelling your notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the place where this might help is if your application has different categories of notifications.

Example: Let us consider u have two categories A and B. You assign two ID's to them. Now if your app gives a notification for A and B [or A after B], you will find that there are two notifications. But say your app sends out two notifications of category A, only the latest one will be displayed.